# Create fragment in viewpager adapter when tab selected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

There are two fragments inside `viewPager`. When the main fragment load the location permission code on the second fragment that work. Want that fragmen work when click the second tab. So I think I need to create this fragment when selected second tab. How can detect and do this?

OurHospitalFragment.kt

```
  viewPager2OurHospital.adapter = adapter
            viewPager2OurHospital.offscreenPageLimit = 1
            TabLayoutMediator(tabLayoutOurHospital, viewPager2OurHospital) { tab, position ->
                when (position) {
                    0 -> tab.text = getString(R.string.list)
                    1 -> tab.text = getString(R.string.map)
                }
            }.attach()

            tabLayoutOurHospital.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
                override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                    tab?.let {
                        viewPager2OurHospital.isUserInputEnabled = tab.position != 1
                    }
                }

                override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                }

                override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                }
            })
```

OurHospitalASMViewPagerAdapter.kt

```
class OurHospitalViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> HospitalListFragment()
            1 -> HospitalMapFragment()
            else -> Fragment()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code line:

```
viewPager2OurHospital.offscreenPageLimit = ViewPager2.OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULT
```

instead of this:

```
viewPager2OurHospital.offscreenPageLimit = 1
```

and I get it what I want.